# iterate list of data classes not working as expected

Tags: kotlin

I have a list of data classes that I am trying to iterate over. 
Here is the data class and where it is created.

```
data class BgaResponse(val columnName: String, val restricted: Boolean, val predictionValue: Double)

val bgaResponse: List<BgaResponse>? = callBgaEndpoint(bgaRequest)
```

printing bgaResponseshows this:

```
[{columnName=col1, restricted=false, predictionValue=0.9963}, {columnName=not_here, restricted=false, predictionValue=0.995941}]
```

I first tried using forEach:

```
bgaResponse?.forEach {
            println(it)
        }
```

this prints nothing. Next i tried accessing each element by index:

```
for(i in 0 until bgaResponse!!.size) {
            println(bgaResponse[i])
        }
```

this prints each element as expected:

```
{columnName=col1, restricted=false, predictionValue=0.9963}
{columnName=not_here, restricted=false, predictionValue=0.995941}
```

I tried printing `bgaResponse[i].columnName` but nothing prints again. Now this isnt making any sense.

Lastly I try:

```
for(i in 0 until bgaResponse!!.size) {
            val x: BgaResponse= bgaResponse[i]
        }
```

this should work, my IDE is telling me bgaResponse[i] is a BgaResponse. This throws back an error:

`org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.package.something.placeholder.model.BgaResponse`

Comment: Every iteration you expose work as expected in my machine, what's the behavior of your callBgaEndpoint(bgaRequest) method ?

Comment: Nothing is obviously wrong with the code you've shown us. If you're having issues, please [edit] your question to add a [mcve].

Comment: Ok, I narrowed it down. For some reason Jackson is having trouble and each element in the list is actually a LinkedHashMap. I can probably fix it, Romain was right it was a problem with callBgaEndpoint. @RomainGoutte-Fangeas